# Zed Attack Proxy Dynamic Certificate option not available

Tags: zap

The option to create dynamic certificates in ZAP is not available.  I cannot see anywhere that it might have moved to and Google is not helping.  I am running it on a Kali VM.

Does anyone know whether it's been removed?  If not, where/how do I get to it?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we've not removed it :/

But you might have accidentally disabled it - have a look in the Options / Extensions - is the ExtensionDynSSL there? If so is it disabled? Enabling it and restarting ZAP should do the trick. If its not there I'd be tempted to try reinstalling..

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Comment: This is enabled, thank you.  I read the answer by @vinicius.olifer and is experiencing the same problem.  It is on a clean install of Kali.

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer since reinstalling it fixed the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: I spent a lot of time searching the CA certificate because the documentation was not clear. I was looking in "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Certificate" instead of "Dynamic SSL Certificates". I found this information in the PDF from the Downloads page (https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Downloads) but I think this information should be added to the official documentation: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpUiDialogsOptionsDynsslcert#generate By the way, the documentation could say that we don't have to generate the certificate because it is already generated at first launch.

Comment: The information to export the ZAP Root CA certificate has even been removed from the latest PDF for version 2.7, any idea why? (hopefully I read version 2.6). I hope you will fix these documentation issues.

Comment: Its been removed from the getting started guide because the 'browser launch' option is easier - just launch browsers from ZAP and they are preconfigured to proxy via ZAP and ignore cert warning. The details for exporting certs are still in the full user guide.

Comment: @SimonBennetts ok but the quick explanation in the PDF was easier to understand. I was looking at the wrong location with the full user guide. I never used the browser launch button before.